# OpenLayers 4 styling draw features

Tags: openlayers

How can I change the color (randomly or iterate through a specific array) of a feature that I draw on the map?

This is my code:

```
// marker layer
Msource = new ol.source.Vector();

markLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: Msource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      opacity: 0.95,
      src: 'http://www..../images/mapplot.png',
     color: "red"
    })
  })
});
```

I have a button that when I click on it allows me to draw that marker with this code:

```
var mark;
var counter = "true";

function addMark(Type) {

  counter = "true";

  mark = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: Msource,
    type: Type
  });

  // limit the marker to 4
  if (Msource.getFeatures().length < 4) {

    map.addInteraction(mark);

    // occurs when you finish to draw the current element
    mark.on("drawend", function(){
      counter = "true";
      drawingMarker();
    });

    // occurs just after you finish to draw the current element
    markLayer.on("change", function(){
      map.removeInteraction(mark);

      if (counter == "true") {
        counter = "false";
        var ind = Msource.getFeatures().length - 1;
        Msource.getFeatures()[ind].setId(MarkId - 1);
      }

    });

  } else {

    map.removeInteraction(mark);

    // show max marker message
    $(".maxmarkers").css("display", "inline");

  }

} // end addDraw


$("#Marker").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addMark("Point");
});
```

I use some other function like remove function and drag feature, for this reason, I assign an incremented ID.

How can I change the color of the marker randomly or through an array (the max marker are 4)?

Here a screenshot of how it looks at the moment, the marker is not red because I'm using another image at the moment but I have another (always png) that change color based on the color in the layer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a style function instead of giving a static style.
Check this:

```
var myColors = ['red','blue','green','yellow'];
var iterator = -1;

function styleFn(f){

var retSytle;


  if (typeof(f.get('styledwithcolor')) != 'undefined'){
  console.log("1",typeof(f.get('styledwithcolor')))

  retSytle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 6,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'white',
            width: 2
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: f.get('styledwithcolor')
          })
        })
      });
  } else {
  console.log("2",typeof(f.get('styledwithcolor')))
  if (iterator == myColors.length-1){
  iterator =-1
  }
iterator = iterator + 1;
  f.set('styledwithcolor',myColors[iterator]);
  retSytle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 6,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'white',
            width: 2
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: myColors[iterator]
          })
        })
      });
  console.log("retSytle",retSytle)
  }
  return [retSytle];
```

}

```
markLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: Msource,
  style: styleFn
});
```

Comment: a very useful and interesting answer, it works but I can't use it. When you plot a new `Marker` the color change for every plotted `Marker`, the same when you drag the feature (on drag change color every pixel you move the cursor) and delete it. I also need that the colors are not repeated

Comment: You have varius options to customise the code above and achieve your goal. I have update my answer!!!!

Comment: check this fiddle -->https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/o0kf4hcc/

Comment: I prefer the first one because I need to use an Icon, I can't use a point (it's a work project) I think I can make it work :) I have to take a look the `event` to prevent that pass from 1 to 3 as is doing now.

Comment: Icons should not be a problem if you include them within your deploy files. I am using a point just for demonstrating. My updated code solves your problems 1)`the color change for every plotted Marker` 2) `I also need that the colors are not repeated`

Comment: actually, it solve just the `1 step`, if you copy your code into my codepen you can see how you have just 2 colors, I think it has to do with `markLayer.on("change", ..` event

Comment: Ok I have updated my code snip. Copy it to your codepen. I have tested it in your codepen and it works fine!

Comment: Now it works :) many thanks, I just have to change from point to the icon and it's done

Comment: Glad to help my friend!